Datadog's Error tracking not working. Error attributes are not been exported or parsed correctly
I have a .net6 api project. I'm using open telemetry (otel) to instrument it and send traces to datadog. I use this image otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest to receive telemetry from my application and send to datadog.
I configured an ExceptionMiddleware to capture all exceptions and create span attributes
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        string userId = GetUserId(context);
        try
        {
            await this._next(context);
        }
        catch (BusinessException bex)
        {
            LogWarning(bex);
            UpdateSpan(bex, userId);
            await this.HandleBadRequest(bex.Message, bex.StackTrace, context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
            string errorId = UpdateSpan(ex, userId);
    
            await this.HandleInternalServerError($"ErrorId: {errorId}", ex.StackTrace, context);
        }
    }

    private static string UpdateSpan(Exception ex, string userId)
    {
        Activity activity = Activity.Current;
        if (activity == null)
            return _defaultActivityId;
    
        string errorId = activity.Id.ToString();
        activity?.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Error, ex.Source);
    
        activity?.SetTag("exception.message", ex.Message);
        activity?.SetTag("exception.stacktrace", ex.StackTrace);
        activity?.SetTag("exception.type", ex.Source);
    
        return errorId;
    }

    private void LogWarning(BusinessException bex)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> errorDict = BuildExceptionAtributes(bex);
    
        using (_logger.BeginScope(errorDict))
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(bex.Message);
    
        };
    }
    
    private void LogError(Exception ex)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> errorDict = BuildExceptionAtributes(ex);
    
        using (_logger.BeginScope(errorDict))
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        };
    }
    
    
    private static Dictionary<string, object> BuildExceptionAtributes(Exception ex)
    {
        var errorDict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            // otel
            ["exception.message"] = ex.Message,
            ["exception.stacktrace"] = ex.StackTrace,
            ["exception.type"] = ex.Source,
        };
        return errorDict;
    }

I created a otel processor to transform exception attributes into error attributes, according to this datadog documentation

Exception attributes are exported correctly, but error attributes are not.
Example:

exception.type becomes error.message,
exception.stacktrace becomes error.stack (ok)
exception.message is ignored
error.type disappear

{
    "exception": {
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "stacktrace": "at blablabla.GetConnection(Int64 userId, Nullable`1 version) in blablabla.cs:line 36",
        "type": "blablabla.WebApi"
    },
    "error": {
        "message": "blablabla.WebApi",
        "stack": "at blablabla.GetConnection(Int64 userId, Nullable`1 version) in blablabla.cs:line 36",
        "type": "does-not-show"
    }
}

This is my otel-colector config.yaml
# This is a configuration file for the OpenTelemetry Collector intended to be
# used in conjunction with the OTLP Exporter example (see ../TestOtlpExporter.cs)
#
# For more information about the OpenTelemetry Collector see:
#   https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector
#
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

exporters:
  logging:
    verbosity: detailed
  datadog:
    api:
      key: some-key
      # site: 

processors:
  # https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/processor/batchprocessor/README.md
  batch:
  attributes/insert:
    actions:
      - key: "error.message"
        action: "insert"
        from_attribute: "exception.message"
  attributes/insert2:
    actions:
      - key: "error.stack"
        action: "insert"
        from_attribute: "exception.stacktrace"
  attributes/insert3:
    actions:
      - key: "error.type"
        action: "insert"
        from_attribute: "exception.type"
      

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch, attributes/insert, attributes/insert2, attributes/insert3]
      exporters: [logging, datadog]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, datadog]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, datadog]

===
I tried to send the error attributes directly, without the otel-colector's processor, and I got exactly the same problem as described above.
private static string UpdateSpan(Exception ex, string userId)
{
    Activity activity = Activity.Current;
    if (activity == null)
        return _defaultActivityId;

    string errorId = activity.Id.ToString();
    activity?.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Error, ex.Source);
    activity?.SetTag("kinvo.user.id", userId);

    activity?.SetTag("exception.message", ex.Message);
    activity?.SetTag("exception.stacktrace", ex.StackTrace);
    activity?.SetTag("exception.type", ex.Source);

    // sending directly
    activity?.SetTag("error.message", ex.Message);
    activity?.SetTag("error.stack", ex.StackTrace);
    activity?.SetTag("error.type", ex.Source);

    return errorId;
}


Hey Vitor, would you be able to try it out without the collector remapping and the manual approach? OTel has span.recordException() method that should do everything automatically, and DD should be able to map it properly.
Here is the recordException doc page: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/instrumentation/#record-exceptions-in-spans
Let me know if it works.

Hi Juliano. In C#, OpenTelemetry depends on the class Activity from System.Diagnostics. And thus, the implementation of span.recordException() is just a wrap around the methods of that class wich is what I do it in the example I provided.

I found the problem. It's in this line of code
activity?.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Error, ex.Source);

When I use the second parameter of SetStatus it overrides the error.message when exported to Datadog.
So I just need to use it like this:
activity?.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Error);

